# How to extract key-value pairs from CSV using Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I have data for one column in my CSV file as :

```
          `column1`
    
   row1 : {'name':'Steve Jobs','location':'America','status':'none'}
   row2 : {'name':'Mark','location':'America','status':'present'}
   row3 : {'name':'Elan','location':'Canada','status':'present'}
```

I want as the output for that column as :

```
`name`       `location`     `status`   

Steve jobs    America        none  
Mark          America        present
Elan          Canada         present
```

But sometimes I have row value like `{'name':'Steve Jobs','location':'America','status':'none'},{'name':'Mark','location':'America','status':'present'}`

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `tMap` and `tExtractDelimitedFields` components.

Flow,

[image]

Below is the step by step explination,

1. Original data -    `row1 : {'name':'Steve Jobs','location':'America','status':'none'}`
2. Substring the value inside the braces using below function
   `row1.Column0.substring(row1.Column0.indexOf("{")+1, row1.Column0.indexOf("}")-1)`  
   Now the result is - `'name':'Steve Jobs','location':'America','status':'none'`

3.Extract single columns to multiple using tExtractDelimitedFields. Since the columns are seperated be `,`, delimiter should be provided as comma. And we have 3 fields in the data, so create 3 fields in the component schema. Below is the snipping of the `tExtractDelimitedFields` component configuration

[image]

Now the result is,

```
     name             location               status
'name':'Steve Jobs'  'location':'America'   'status':'none'
'name':'Mark'        'location':'America'   'status':'present'
'name':'Elan'        'location':'Canada'    'status':'present'
```

4. Again using one more tMap, replace the column names and single quotes from the data,

   ```
    row2.name.replaceAll("'name':", "").replaceAll("'", "") 
    row2.location.replaceAll("'location':", "").replaceAll("'", "") 
    row2.status.replaceAll("'status':", "").replaceAll("'", "")
   ```
5. Your final result is below,

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks again. Do you know how to change milliseconds into Timestamp using Talend?

Comment: Can you ping the exact value, so that can try

Comment: I have more than 100 rows in one column.  sample value : 1587740000000, 1590600000000, 1588880000000, 1589040000000, 1589040000000.

Comment: And what is your expected result? I mean in which format you need?

Comment: 1587740000000 =  24-04-2020 20:23:20

Comment: Can you add this in a new question. So that others will also be helpful